# How to change the pre-defined <h2> tag located in section title of home page to <h1> tag in wordpress appsperia theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using wordpress 4.4.9 and following appsperia theme to design a website.
So the theme is taking the pre-defined section title  tag on the home page whereas i would like to change it to 'h1' tag.

I tried making changes in the index.php located in the home directory of wp-content/plugins/ and include home.php considered in changes but no luck.

Help would be appreciated.

In admin panel i have Front Page placed in front of Home,and also there is no option to edit the tag style.
[image: Home Page description in admin]

Comment: you need to change either `wp-content/themes/appsperia/the landing page you selected` or open admin panel->go to pages->home page>edit it and change.

Comment: @AlivetoDie i've changed in the index.php too as mentioned in the question but no chance.

Comment: you changed `index.php` of `wp-content/plugins/` what i am saying is that go to wp-content/themes/appsperia/ and check which landing page you selected. change in that page. Or through admin panel open your home page and edit there

Comment: I changed the index.php located in wp-content/themes/appsperia/  too and going through admin panel Home page i observe it to be "Home — Front Page" so i again changed my wp-content/themes/appsperia/front-page.php too but still no chance

Comment: i can only help this much.Sorry. Or you can provide me the link of your website so that i can check it.

Comment: How to check the landing page i've selected for home page. @AlivetoDie and plus i have edited the question so see if you can look in for some help

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be any page. First, you mean themes directory, not the plugins directory. I can't reply comment, so I wrote it on here then...

If you have front-page.php page, check it.
I will list all page, you should be check then.

1. front-page.php
2. home.php
3. page.php (if it is a page)
4. index.php (if all the other page is not exists)
5. single.php

You should check this, to figure out, how wordpress handle theming.

[image]

It should be one of it. these files are located in themes directory. You can set any page to be front-page, and any page can use any template, which listed in the page editor.

My advise:
the theme is likely not developed by you, I assumed. If it is the case, extend it using child theme. In case, the theme were updated in the future, it doesn't affect your changes.

You can check it out on here. You can just replace one single file and using your own instead, without change all the theme files.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes